# How to get headers from NESTjs controller (graphql schema first)

Tags: typescript, http, graphql, nestjs

I have a NEST graphql API and i need to create a GUARD to validate every access by accessToken. i'm sending the Bearer token in all graphql requests and I need to retrieve them from the server to check if the access is valid.

that is my auth.guard:

```
@UseInterceptors(LoggerInterceptor)
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
        Logger.debug(`starting AuthGuard...`);
    }

    async canActivate(
        context: ExecutionContext
    ): Promise<boolean> {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

        Logger.debug(`canActivate? ${inspect(request)}`);

        try {

            if (request && request.headers) {
                const user = await this._authService.userProfileInfo(request.headers['Authorization']);

                if (user && user.data && user.data.email) {
                    Logger.debug(`canActivate :D!!`);
                    return true;
                }
            }

        } catch (error) {
            Logger.debug(`cannotActivate D:!!`);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to access the headers of the request. The context only carries the query/mutation parameters with it. Any one knows how to access headers with graphql schema first? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a GqlExecution and attach the context to it.
The request object can be gotten from ctx.getContext().

Below is a modified version of your code.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
    Logger.debug(`starting AuthGuard...`);
  }

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const authorization = ctx.getContext().req?.headers?.authorization;
    const bearer = authorization.split(' ')[0];
    const token = authorization.split(' ')[1];

    try {
      // your logic
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Read more here https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/other-features#execution-context